# Can you prevent users from modifying dreamweaver templates?

Tags: security, authentication, templates, dreamweaver

Everything I read about Dreamweaver Templates says that the author sets the Editable Regions of the template and then users can only edit those regions, not locked regions.

But what prevents a malicious user from opening up the Template itself and changing that?

You could of course enforce this separation by using, for example, folder permissions, but is there any kind of authentication/permission system in Dreamweaver itself? Does the template "know" which user is its author?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How would it benefit a malicious user to modify a template? It's not like they can do anything with the modified template. They can't make you serve it or use it unless they have the very same permissions they could use to replace the template with another template entirely.

Comment: Perhaps "malicious" was the wrong word, but a user who doesn't want to be limited to the options you've allowed them in the template. They could indeed replace an entire template, which would be just as much of a problem. My question really is "do you have any actual CONTROL over what users do, or is it just a matter of good will?".

Comment: Since Dreamweaver can't stop them from replacing the entire template, and that would create the same problem, Dreamweaver can't solve this problem.

Comment: That's been confirmed for me now, which answers my question, and also see Zoredache's answer which tells me there are Adobe systems with this functionality, but Dreamweaver isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the end users have Dreamweaver then they will be pretty much able to do anything.  The template functionality becomes far more useful when you give un-privileged users Contribute instead of Dreamweaver.   You combine this with the Contribute Publishing Services, and you can provide access control.  For page creation and editing.